# How to send 'text/event-stream' data from express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

Trying to get a basic server-sent-event working with express.js on server side:

`index.js`:

```
const app        = require('express')();
const index_html = require('path').join(__dirname, 'index.html');

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
{
    res.sendFile(index_html);
});

app.get('/data', (req, res) =>
{
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');

    setInterval(() =>
    {
        res.write(new Date().toISOString() + '\n\n');
    }, 1000);
});

app.listen('7000');
```

`index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id='result'>No Data Yet</h1>
    <script>
    var source = new EventSource('data');
    source.onmessage = function(event)
    {
        console.log('invoked');
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = event.data + '<br>';
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

The `source.onmessage` never triggers.

Comment: `Filler text for` don't do that, that's lazy

Comment: I don't think any additional details are needed here

Comment: how about adding some observations from any debugging you tried, like, what do you observe in the **developer** tools console and/or network tabs. Can you see any network activity regarding your `EventSource` for example?

Comment: @JaromandaX An additional GET request sent to `/data` route

Comment: So, all you see is the `GET /data` - you can't see any response headers? Perhaps you need a better browser if your browser has such poor developer tools :p

Comment: @JaromandaX no response/no transfer of any kind based on firefox network tab (latest Firefox on my distro's repository 57.0.4 (64-bit))

Comment: ahh, see the problem, try `res.write('data: ' + new Date().toISOString() + '\n\n')`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. If you add at it as answer below, I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Server side events need to send data in a particular (text) format, specifically, to send data, you need a line of text in the format

```
data: text to send goes here
```

other types of data in a single event can be `type`, `id`, and `retry`

any line that doesn't start with

```
data:
type:
id:
retry:
```

is *ignored*, hence why you were not getting any events

simple change

```
setInterval(() =>
{
    res.write('data: ' + new Date().toISOString() + '\n\n');
}, 1000);
```

Though, I'd write it like

```
    setInterval(() => res.write(`data: ${new Date().toISOString()}\n\n`), 1000);
```

> Further reading [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Fields)